# jquery wrapping groups of adjacent elements

Tags: jquery, css, dom

I have a cms that lets users insert blocks of content on a page. There are different types of content block available to the user and they can be inserted in any order. An example high-level dom structure might look something like this:

```
<p>Some rich text</p>

<div class="box">...</div>
<div class="box">...</div>
<div class="box">...</div>

<h3>Some  more rich text</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>

<div class="box">...</div>
<div class="box">...</div>
```

What I want to do is wrap any adjacent 'box' divs in a wrapping 'container' div. So in the example above there would be two 'container' divs inserted as there are two groups of box divs, resulting in:

```
<p>Some rich text</p>

<div class="container">
    <div class="box">...</div>
    <div class="box">...</div>
    <div class="box">...</div>
</div>

<h3>Some  more rich text</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>

<div class="container">
    <div class="box">...</div>
    <div class="box">...</div>
</div>
```

I don't think there is a clever way to do it with css selectors, so does anyone know of anyway to do this with jQuery?

Comment: Post desired result. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you could do it like this [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7NCDf/) I've just whipped up.

This basically loops through each `.box` adding it to an array and determining whether the next element also has the `.box` class:

```
var collection = [];
$('.box').each(function() {
    var nextBox = $(this).next().hasClass('box');
    ...
    collection.push($(this));
})
```

If it the next element *doesn't* have a `.box` class, it creates the containing divider, puts it on the page before the first `.box` within the `collection` array is located, then uses `appendTo` to move all the `.box` dividers into it:

```
    if(!nextBox)
    {
        var container = $('<div class="collection"></div>');
        container.insertBefore(collection[0]);
        for(i=0;i<collection.length;i++)
        {
            collection[i].appendTo(container);
        }
        collection = [];
    }
```

Comment: This turned out to the be the most robust solution in my case.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

1. [`.nextUntil`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/), to get all the next `.box`.
2. [`.andSelf`](https://api.jquery.com/andself/) to add the current element to the collection
3. [`.wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) to wrap each collection to a different `.container`

```js
$('.box').not('.box+.box').each(function(){
  $(this).nextUntil(':not(.box)').addBack().wrapAll('<div class="container" />');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Some rich text</p>

<div class="box">...</div>
<div class="box">...</div>
<div class="box">...</div>

<h3>Some  more rich text</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>

<div class="box">...</div>
<div class="box">...</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/gonino/edit?html,js

Comment: Perfect, but `andSelf()` is deprecated. It is `addBack` now. Ran into a problem with this using cheerio (jQuery clone for Node).

Comment: ...which also doesn't have `wrapAll`, so maybe this won't work for me after all. :( :P

Comment: Thanks. I tried to replace to `.addBack()` and it's seems to work fine. Isn't?

Answer (score 2):

The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/jdelight/XutA6/5/
Here's a possible solution using css which lets you style the blocks with a single background colour and border. The HTML would be something like this:

```
    <div class="block">this is block 1</div>
    <div class="block">this is block 2</div>
    <div class="block">this is block 3</div>
    <div class="block">this is block 4</div>
    <div class="block">this is block 5</div>
```

And the CSS would be:

```
            /* style all blocks with the required background colour and border */
        .block {
            background: #eee;
            color: #000;
            border: 1px solid red;
            border-bottom: 0;
            padding: 20px;
            width: 400px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            /* remove the rounded corners from he bottom left/right */
            border-bottom-left-radius:0;
            border-bottom-right-radius:0;
            position: relative;
        }
        /* style all adjacent blocks and remove the radius - so the top block has a radius and the others don't */
        .block + .block {
            border-radius: 0;
            border-top: 0;
        }

        /* create a cheeky block with content after which sits below all blocks */
        /* so it's hidden from all the blocks above it apart from the very bottom one (see bottom: -10px) */
        /* then style the rounded corners on that one */
        .block::after {
            content:'.';
            display: block;
            background: red;
            height: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            border-bottom: 1px solid red;
            border-left:  1px solid red;
            border-right:  1px solid red;
            bottom: -10px;
            width: 440px;
            background: #eee;
            left:-1px;
            border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
            border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
        }
```

Comment: Puts my answer to shame! Good job!

Comment: This is nearly there but I couldn't use it in the end as the absolute positioning means I get issues with it overlapping content at the bottom.