# Changing a tag <a> to <div> with DOMDocument on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, domdocument

I'm a beginner in PHP and I would like to set up several functions to replace specific code bits on WordPress (including plugin elements that I can't edit directly).

Below is an example (first line: initial result, second line: desired result):

```
<a href="" class="vcard author"><span class="fn" itemprop="name">Gael Beyries</span></a>

<div class="vcard author"><span class="fn" itemprop="name">Gael Beyries</span></div>
```

PS: I came across this topic: [Parsing WordPress post content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20820848/parsing-wordpress-post-content/20822406) but the example is too complicated for what I want to do. Could you present me an example code that solves this problem so I can try to modify it to modify other html elements?

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure how this fits into WP, I have basically taken the code from the linked answer and adapted it to your requirements.

I've assumed you want to find the `<a>` tags with `class="vcard author"` and this is the basis of the XPath expression.  The code in the `foreach()` loop just copies the data into a new node and replaces the old one...

```
function replaceAWithDiv($content){
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($content);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $aTags = $xpath->query('//a[@class="vcard author"]');

    foreach($aTags as $a){
        // Create replacement element
        $div = $dom->createElement("div");
        $div->setAttribute("class", "vcard author");
        // Copy contents from a tag to div
        foreach ($a->childNodes as $child ) {
            $div->appendChild($child);
        }
        // Replace a tag with div
        $a->parentNode->replaceChild($div, $a);
    }
    return $dom->saveHTML();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to make this example. How can I add this code to functions.php? Which add_action or add_filter should I use?

Comment: Have you tried something similar to the answer you pointed to - `add_filter( 'the_content', 'replaceAWithDiv', 20 );`?

Comment: Unless you can get some error to find what is happening - there isn't a lot I know about WP to help.

Comment: 503 bad gateway on one page and all accents that are incorrectly displayed on another page.